# Does core isolation protect me against malware?

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention

Does [Windows 11 core isolation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-protection-in-windows-security-afa11526-de57-b1c5-599f-3a4c6a61c5e2) protect me against malware or does it have nothing to do with it? For example, an unsophisticated hacker with metasploit, nmap, msvenom or tools like that could create obfuscated malware or code that can run on a PC with the isolated core and RAM or that type of code. Or does malware for reverse shells not need to access those protected parts of the system?

Comment: You keep confusing "reverse shell" with malware and exploits. A reverse shell happens *after* malware exploits a machine.

Comment: A lot of thanks, maybe u can say me how can an unsophisticated hacker exploit my machine outside my network without pishing or social engineering

Comment: As I said from your previous question, that's too open-ended to answer. There are lots of ways. Hacking the router or your phone first is one way. But as I also said, I would challenge the idea that you are under an on-going "hack".

Comment: But let's say that you are a hacker who uses conventional techniques, who does not have deep knowledge and who possibly learns by watching YouTube and forums, what kind of attacks to steal information from outside the network could he perform knowing a public IP and without the network having open ports or portfowarding and with firewalls and antivirus activated, from start to finish, I'm talking about not very complex attacks

Comment: Against the youtube-educated crowd basic steps like firewalls in routers and antivirus on the desktop are enough for usual private household environments. But these guys are not a significant threat actor anyway.

Comment: @carlosnavarrete this new question has ***nothing*** to do with Win11 core isolation ... Just like your previous question, this is unfocused and you are trying to solve one problem by asking about a whole range of others. We can't help with such a questioning approach.

Comment: For some reason I can't find out what core isolation *actually does*, but it sounds like yet another defense-in-depth feature, that makes things harder to "hack", but does not necessarily *prevent* "hacking".

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things confused together. It is possible to create malware that includes a reverse shell that does not require "hacking" the system.

Core isolation *helps* to isolate high-security parts of Windows memory to prevent abuse and misuse of memory to gain privilege isolation. So, from this perspective, core isolation helps prevent certain ways of gaining access to the system through exploiting other programs.

As with all things in security, there is no single, simple, conclusive solution to complex problems.

Comment: Might be usefule to add https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/core-isolation-e30ed737-17d8-42f3-a2a9-87521df09b78 for clarity as what "core isolation" is from microsoft.